What are good introductory books for contact geometry in non-equilibrium thermo?
As far as I can understand, Mrugala's paper on the geometry of thermodynamic processes covers introductory prerequisites for the contact formalism applied to thermodynamics, however, I know there's a lot of competing formalisms for out of equilibrium thermodynamics including

GENERIC (Gremela)


Port Hamiltonian (Ramirez)


Contact Control Hamiltonian
(Eberard)

But I can't find any introductory material on the basic starting points for contact non equilibrium thermo. As I understand, it should start with defining the evolution of differential volume elements in the system eventually converging to a single state where (s,p,u, etc) are the same for all the system's constituents, but it seems that some formalisms overlook this or overcomplicate things to get rid of the dependences on spatial coordinates.
Is there any agreed upon material on the fundamentals of contact geometry in non-equilibrium thermo?

Can you please link the paper you are talking about?

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0034487700900120
